# Get whole .docx text with office automation, including font and properties (as bold, italic...)

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

so I am trying to select text from a word document, that contains text in italic, bold, have specific font family.

So I found this code to select all the text :

```
//doc is the opened document with office automation, this part works
string text = doc.Content.Text;
int end = text.Length;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = doc.Range(Start: 0, End: end);
range.Select();
```

Then i use it, to copy the text into a Outlook message :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook = new   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)outlook.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
oMsg.Body = range.Text ;
```

And then, when I watch the message html body, I only ot calibri font, and no bold or italic.

What i want to attempt is the same thing as we got when we do it manually :

open word document
select all text then copy (ctrl + c)
Create a mail in outlook
Paste the text in the mail (ctrl + v).

When it is done this way, It is well reproduced (font family, bold etc are well there), but when it is done in the code, it only take the text.

See the differences in this pic (the one bellow is made programmatically, the one bottom, manually):

[image]

How can I fix this(if possible)?

**Edit** : after the answer from Eugene, I add this :

```
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector insp = oMsg.GetInspector;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordEditorDoc = insp.WordEditor;
```

But then, I don't get how I put the doc text, into the word Editor Object I created. I can still made a `wordEditorDoc  = doc;` but the result is not better than before.

Answer (score 1):

The Body property contains a raw text. A possible way is to use HTMLBody or Word editor. I think the most convinient way is to use the Word object model to copy the content between documents (the Word existing document and the message body). As you probably know Outlook uses Word as an email editor in Outlook. So, you can use the Word object model for formatting email messages in Outlook.

The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class (from the Word object model) which represents the message body.

You can read more about possible ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article in MSDN.

Comment: I don't get how I can make a real copy of the word document , that copy the whole prooperties as I whant to (bold etc).When you have your inspector, and your word editor, what do you do? Each time I check the HTMLBody of oMsg, I never get the bold, or italic part...

Comment: Did you have a chance to check out the article mentioned in my post? It provides a sample code. Anyway, Outlook doesn't reflect changes made in the UI to their objects. You need to Save the item if you want to see changes.